# What Kubuntu 20.04 / 22.04 repositories to add if upgraded from Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, kubuntu, kde

I had Kubuntu 18.04. I just did `apt dist-upgrade` to 20.04 LTS. I can see that "Ubuntu part" is upgraded, but I still have old plasma and KDE:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep plasma-desktop
ii  plasma-desktop                                4:5.18.8-0ubuntu0.1                                 amd64        Tools and widgets for the desktop
ii  plasma-desktop-data                           4:5.18.8-0ubuntu0.1                                 all          Tools and widgets for the desktop data files
```

I am going to upgrade to Kubuntu 20.04 LTS / then to Kubuntu 22.04 LTS. It looks I miss some repositories. I was searching the Internet, but cannot find the list.

1. What Kubuntu repositories should I add to upgrade to 20.04 ?
2. What Kubuntu repositories should I add to upgrade to 22.04 ?

Of course I know I can download the image and upgrade (or pull out) from the image ...

Comment: There are no repositories to add. The versions you show for the packages are the correct version for 20.04. Did you realize that this is Plasma 5.18.8?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me. So I just need to upgrade to 22.04 and I should have newer plasma/kde. I thought I have old plasma because 
I must have previously some plasma upgraded from some ppa in 18.04 and I thought that nothing changed. I found the  "Kubuntu vs KDE vs Plasma vs QT " version table,here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubuntu